# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../containers/Layout' in '/home/yusquen/Projectss/react-shop/src/components'

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, npm

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vrJS.png) Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../containers/Layout' in '/home/yusquen/Projectss/react-shop/src/components']

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHJyx.jpg)

```
Module not found: Error:
Can't resolve '../containers/Login' in '/home/yusquen/Projectss/react-shop/src/components'
```

Comment: Could you add the *code* of the `Login` component?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your folder is called "container" not "container**s**" (no s).

Comment: yes, I fix it but I have the problem yet

Comment: yes, I fix it but I have the problem yet